# Definition of Normal Bundle and little exercise

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles

I need to show that, given a manifold $M$ and its diagonal $\Delta\subset M\times M$, we have $T\Delta\cong\mathcal{N}_{\Delta|M\times M}$, where $T\Delta$ is the tangent bundle and $\mathcal{N}_{\Delta|M\times M}$ is the normal bundle of $\Delta$.

The definition of normal bundle my professor told me is the following.
For every $p\in \Delta$, define 
$$
(\mathcal{N}_{\Delta|M\times M})_p:=\frac{T_p(M\times M)}{T_p\Delta}
$$
Gluing all together we obtain
$$
\mathcal{N}_{\Delta|M\times M}=\frac{T(M\times M)|\Delta}{T\Delta}
$$
I was looking at Bott-Tu classic book, and I found out a different definition of normal bundle. They say that it's defined by the exact sequence
$$
0\rightarrow T\Delta\rightarrow T(M\times M)|\Delta\rightarrow\mathcal{N}_{\Delta|M\times M}\rightarrow 0
$$.
I think that to solve my initial problem is better to use this definition. But what I can't understand is

- Why the two definitions are equivalent?
- How is exactly defined the exact sequence above, i.e. how are those maps defined?

Comment: I suppose you mean $T(M \times M)$ instead of $TM \times M$?

Comment: Yes, I do. I've just edited the post

Comment: Please review the meaning of a short exact sequence of vector bundles (spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is almost tautological, which makes it a bit hard to explain on the internet.

Let's forget about bundles, but consider just vector spaces. If $V\subset W$ is a subspace there is a canonical map $V\rightarrow W$ which just maps the element $v\in V$ to $v\in W$. This map is the inclusion and is injective.

Similarly, there is a canonical map $W\rightarrow W/V$ mapping $w\in W$ to $[w]$ (the equivalence class of all vectors in $W$ that differ from $w$ by an element in $V$). This map is called the projection and is surjective.

Clearly for $v\in V$, we see that $v\in W$ and $[v]=0\in W/V$ which shows that the sequence

$$
0\rightarrow V\rightarrow W\rightarrow W/V\rightarrow 0
$$

is exact.

In general, saying that we have an injective map $i:V\rightarrow W$ (which we can view as a way of seeing $V$ as a subspace of $W$) is the same as saying that we have a (very) short exact sequence

$$
0\rightarrow V\rightarrow W
$$

We can always complete it to a short exact sequence
$$
0\rightarrow V\rightarrow W\rightarrow W/i(V)\rightarrow 0
$$

By projecting to the quotient as before. There is nothing more to say about bundles.